# can i run my app with a link?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app. And the customur wanted that:I will send an activation mail and when the user clicked it frım iphone my application will open. Is it possible really? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you want to do is implement your own custom URL scheme for your app. Then make a link with that scheme in the email.

See the section on this page about [implementing your own scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).